# regex including greater than sign

Tags: regex, special-characters, breadcrumbs

I am trying to parse a breadcrumb and have it sussed for most parts (in other regex) - all except the 3rd data string.

Example breadcrumb
*Semiconductors - ICs > Data & Signal Conversion > Digital-to-Analog Converters (DAC) > Product View*

For this instance the breadcrumb **must contain 'Product View'** and also **3 greater than signs**. In these conditions I need the text after the 2nd > sign up to yet excluding the following >

In this example it would be 'Digital-to-Analog Converters (DAC)'

This regex works except for it includes the greater than *'Digital-to-Analog Converters (DAC) **>**'*

```
^([^>]*>){3}[^>](.*)(Product View)$
```

Please could someone help?

Comment: rephrase your question, I am not really getting what exactly you want

Comment: What is the programming language you are using? Here is how this text can be captured: [`^(?:[^>]*\s*>){2}\s*([^>]*)\s*>`](https://regex101.com/r/lO0tY7/2). Result is in Group 1. The final `\s*>` makes it possible to omit the last `>`. If it can be at the end of string, use an alternation: [`^(?:[^>]*\s*>){2}\s*([^>]*)(?:\s*$|\s*>)`](https://regex101.com/r/lO0tY7/3).

Comment: I need to use plain Regex as it is for Adobe Omniture classification rule builder. I have looked at groups but I couldn't get them to work with the other criteria - that and I'm a novice at this.

Comment: Maybe this: _https://regex101.com/r/rG5lY5/2_

Comment: Thanks stribizhev, that works great :)

Comment: Hi stribizhev, I've realised the code you sent which takes either scenario has the final space on the end if there is a Product View, is there a way to remove that?

Comment: Just check my answer. Trailing space is not captured.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?:[^>]*\s*>){2}\s*([^>]*?)\s*(?:$|>)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lO0tY7/4)

Here, `^` matches the beginning of the string, `(?:[^>]*\s*>){2}` matches 2 occurrences of 0 or more characters other than `>` followed with optional whitespace, then `\s*` matches optional whitespace, then `([^>]*?)` matches and captures 0 or more characters other than `>` up to the end of string or next `>`.

Comment: Note that the space is not captured into Group 1 because I used lazy matching with `[^>]*?`.